# How to use html in child theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, parent-child

I am confused as I have installed child theme and I want to remove a top bar From menu. I was checking for HTML code in the activated child theme but I am not getting that HTML code Which I want to remove.

Comment: Hello, You need just copy the parent theme header and change those HTML as you need.

Comment: Hey, you can also write custom CSS relating the class of the section you want to hide.

Comment: thanks for ur reply let me try

Answer (score 0):

just check your main theme folder where `header.php` file is listed. copy that file in your child theme directory and modify as per your need. wordpress auto overwrites main theme header file with child theme header file.